# Whats the command to get spark driver memory in spark shell

Tags: apache-spark

I know spark related configuration can be get via spark-env.sh file however what would be the command to get it from spark-shell ?
For example to get spark.driver.memory shall I use

```
set spark.driver.memory
```

above isn't working

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the memory as a configuration while launching spark-shell

```
spark-shell --conf spark.driver.memory=2g
```

This will start a spark shell with 2g of driver memory. In order to access it in spark shell, you can do the following.

```
val conf = sparkContext.getConf
val driverMemory = conf.get("spark.driver.memory")
```

This will return `String = 2g`.

Comment: Thanks but once I launch the spark-shell how to retrieve the value